# Reducing insane flex lexer expansion?

Tags: flex-lexer

I have written a flex lexer to handle the text in [BYOND](http://byond.com)'s .dmi file format. The contents inside are (key, value) pairs delimited by '='. Valid keys are all essentially keywords (such as "width"), and invalid keys are not errors: they are just ignored.

Interestingly, the current state of BYOND's .dmi parser uses *everything* prior to the '=' as its keyword, and simply ignores any excess junk. This means "\twidth123" is recognized as "width".

The crux of my problem is in allowing for this irregularity. In doing so my generated lexer expands from ~40-50KB to ~13-14MB. For reference, I present the following contrived example:

```
%option c++ noyywrap

fill    [^=#\n]*

%%
{fill}version{fill}     { return 0; }
{fill}width{fill}       { return 0; }
{fill}height{fill}      { return 0; }
{fill}state{fill}       { return 0; }
{fill}dirs{fill}        { return 0; }
{fill}frames{fill}      { return 0; }
{fill}delay{fill}       { return 0; }
{fill}loop{fill}        { return 0; }
{fill}rewind{fill}      { return 0; }
{fill}movement{fill}    { return 0; }
{fill}hotspot{fill}     { return 0; }
%%
```

fill is the rule that is used to merge the keywords with "anything before the =". Running flex on the above yields a ~13MB lex.yy.cc on my computer. Simply removing the kleene star (*) in the fill rule yields a 45KB lex.yy.cc file; however, obviously, this then makes the lexer incorrect.

Are there any tricks, flex options, or lexer hacks to avoid this insane expansion? The only things I can think of are:

1. Disallow "width123" to represent "width", which is undesirable as then technically-correct files could not be parsed.
2. Make one rule that is simply [^=\n]+ to return some *identifier* token, and pick out the keyword in the parser. This seems suboptimal to me as well, particularly because different keywords have different value types and it seems most natural to be able to handle "'width' '=' INT" and "'version' '=' FLOAT" in the parser instead of "ID '=' VALUE" followed by picking out the keyword in the identifier, making sure the value is of the right type, etc.
3. I could make the rule {fill}(width|height|version|...){fill}, which does indeed keep the generated file small. However, while regular expression parsers tend to produce "captures," flex just gives me yytext and re-parsing that for a keyword to produce the desired token seems to be very undesirable in terms of algorithmic complexity.

Comment: Is that really the way the .dmi parser works, or is it that it ignores non-alphabetic characters before the keyword? Would `awidth = 31` be the same as `width = 31`? Because if you change the first `{fill}` to `[^#=\n[:alpha:]]*`, you won't have the exponential blowup in table size. (The second `{fill}` doesn't matter.)

Comment: Yes, currently it just ignores all of the junk. So "aabbbzzzwidth123 = 31" becomes "width = 31"

Comment: Well, that's ugly. How does it handle settings which have two different keywords? The first one? The last one? Some arbitrary one? (eg. `xxwidtheightxx=17`)

Comment: That's something I'll have to tinker with to find out. I assume it takes the first one and that's what I wrote my lexer to do. It should be noted that the maintainer of the software informed me that in the future the format may use stricter keywords, which I and any sensible software developer would much prefer.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer based on the first match theory. Obviously, I agree that stricter parsing would be better (and probably also more efficient); I personally wouldn't bother maintaining compatibility with input which is complete garbage (leading alphabetic characters, for example), even if you want to allow *some* deviations from strictly correct. But obviously that's your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `fill` a separate rule of its own that does nothing, and remove it from all the other rules, and separate its definition from whitespace for clarity:

```
whitespace [ \t\f]
fill [^#=\n]
%%
{whitespace}+ ;
{fill}+ ;
```

I would probably also avoid building the keywords into the lexer and just use an `identifier [a-zA-Z]+` rule that does a table lookup. And finally add a rule to catch the `=`:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

to let the parser handle all special characters.

Comment: Ah! A separate rule, of course. Since flex takes the longest match, wouldn't "width123" match {fill}+ instead of a "width" rule? A table lookup for your [a-zA-Z]+ rule also wouldn't work with garbled "zzzzzwidth". I do think having a rule just for {fill} (single character) would have some merit. I'll have to use another lexer state so that "widthheight" only produces "width" and not "width" and "height" tokens. Given that this should suit my needs, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes of course, you'll have to refine the `fill` rule further. Another takeaway from this is not to try to build a parser with *flex.* Use it for screening (whitespace and fill) and scanning (identifiers or keywords or special characters).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a problem flex is "good at", but it can be solved if it is precisely defined. In particular, it is important to know *which* of the keywords should be returned if the random string of letters before the <kbd>=</kbd> contains more than one keyword. For example, suppose the input is:

```
garbage_widtheight_moregarbage = 42
```

Now, is that setting the `width` or the `height`?

Remember that flex scanners will choose the rule with longest match, and of rules with equally long matches, the first one in the lexical description.

So the model presented in the OP:

```
fill    [^=#\n]*

%%
{fill}width{fill}       { return 0; }
{fill}height{fill}      { return 0; }
  /* SNIP */
```

will always prefer `width` to `height`, because the matches will be the same length (both terminate at the last character before the <kbd>=</kbd>), and the `width` pattern comes first in the file. If the rules were written in the opposite order, `height` would be preferred.

On the other hand, if you removed the second `{fill}`:

```
{fill}width{fill}       { return 0; }
{fill}height{fill}      { return 0; }
```

then the *last* keyword in the input (in this case, `height`) will be preferred, because that one has the longer match.

The most likely requirement, however, is that the *first* keyword be recognized, so neither of the preceding will work. In order to match the first keyword, it is necessary to first match the *shortest* possible sequence of `{fill}`. And since flex does not implement non-greedy repetition, that can only be done with a character-by-character span.

Here's an example, using start conditions. Note that we hold onto the keyword token until we actually find the `=`, in case the `=` is not found.

```
 /* INITIAL:    beginning of a line
  * FIND_EQUAL: keyword recognized, looking for the =
  * VALUE:      = recognized, lexing the right-hand side
  * NEXT_LINE:  find the next line and continue the scan
  */
%x FIND_EQUAL VALUE
%%
    int keyword;
"[#=]".*         /* Skip comments and lines with no recognizable keyword */
version           { keyword = KW_VERSION; BEGIN(FIND_EQUAL); }
width             { keyword = KW_WIDTH;   BEGIN(FIND_EQUAL); }
height            { keyword = KW_HEIGHT;  BEGIN(FIND_EQUAL); }
  /* etc. */
.|\n              /* Skip any other single character, or newline */

<FIND_EQUAL>{
  [^=#\n]*"="     { BEGIN(VALUE); return keyword; }
  "#".*           { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
  \n              { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
}

<VALUE>{
  "#".*           { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
  \n              { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
  [[:blank:]]+    ;  /* Ignore space and tab characters */
  [[:digit:]]+    { yylval.ival = atoi(yytext);
                    BEGIN(NEXT_LINE); return INTEGER;
                  }
  [[:digit:]]+"."[[:digit:]]*|"."[[:digit:]]+ {
                    yylval.fval = atod(yytext);
                    BEGIN(NEXT_LINE); return FLOAT;
                  }
  \"([^"]|\\.)*\" { char* s = malloc(yyleng - 1);
                    yylval.sval = s;
                    /* Remove quotes and escape characters */
                    yytext[yyleng - 1] = '\0';
                    do {
                      if (*++yytext == '\\') ++yytext;
                      *s++ = *yytext;
                    } while (*yytext);
                    BEGIN(NEXT_LINE); return STRING;
                  }
    /* Other possible value token types */
  .               BEGIN(NEXT_LINE); /* bad character in value */ 
}                         
<NEXT_LINE>.*\n?  BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

In the escape-removal code, you might want to translate things like `\n`. And you might also want to avoid string values with physical newlines. And a bunch of etceteras. It's only intended as a model.